# PowerShell - carve out a part of the select-string output

Tags: powershell, azcopy, select-string

I'm copying a large amount of data using AzCopy and I need to have a way to retrieve the files that failed to copy.

AzCopy creates a nice log from each job and  can do something like this:

```
Select-String -Path C:\Users\XXX\.azcopy\Projects\304c22cc-d37d-d743-7597-a160ac0ebad2.log -Pattern 'UPLOADFAILED'
```

But the output looks like that:

*.azcopy\Projects\304c22cc-d37d-d743-7597-a160ac0ebad2.log:25528:2021/01/04 16:45:19 ERR: [P#0-T#2357] UPLOADFAILED:
%5C%5C\UNC\fileserver.contoso.network\PROJ$\AAAA\BBBB\CCCC\Eigenerkl+�rungen.pdf_DOC001719.pdf : 000 : Could not check destination file existence. ->
github.com/Azure/azure-storage-file-go/azfile.newStorageError, /home/vsts/go/pkg/mod/github.com/!azure/azure-storage-file-go@v0.8.0/azfile/zc_storage_error.go:42*

I need to carve out only the file path and name from this output. In the exampe below, I need to carve out:

fileserver.contoso.network\PROJ$\AAAA\BBBB\CCCC\Eigenerkl+�rungen.pdf_DOC001719.pdf

Does anyone have any idea how? I can't search based on the file name because I have over 2000 files that have failed and I need to carve out all of them.

Kind regards,
Wojciech

Answer (score 0):

- Define your pattern [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) so that it captures only the part of interest.
- Access the captured part via the `.Matches` collection of the [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) instance(s) output by [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string).

```
$file = 'C:\Users\XXX\.azcopy\Projects\304c22cc-d37d-d743-7597-a160ac0ebad2.log'

# Define the pattern as a regex that captures only the part of interest.
$pattern = '(?<=UPLOADFAILED:%5C%5C\\UNC\\)[^_]+'

(Select-String -Pattern $pattern -LiteralPath $file).Matches.Value
```

The assumptions are:

- `%5C%5C\UNC\` is a fixed string preceding the path of interest (note how the `\` are escaped as `\\` in order to treat them *verbatim* in the regex).
- A `_` character marks the end of the path.

Also note that `Select-String` matches case-*insensitively* by default; use `-CaseSensitive` as needed.

Finally, the presence of `�` (REPLACEMENT CHARACTER, [`U+FFFD`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd)) in your sample data suggests that the file's character encoding is being misinterpreted, which you may be able to fix via the `-Encoding` parameter. Then again, these characters may point to a *prior* problem that caused these paths to be listed as failed to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!
You pointed me in the right direction. Damn I need to learn regex.
I made a small adjustment in the pattern though. This worked for me:

```
$pattern2 = '(?<=UPLOADFAILED:\s%5C%5C\?\\UNC\\).*(?=\s\:\s000)'
```

Thanks again,
Wojtek